# Delete the previous and next element from an array while using array.map() in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I delete the previous and next element from an array while using array.map();

In the code below, when I get to '*crossover*' I want to delete both '*SUV*' and '*sedan*'.

The following code deletes '*sedan*' and '*truck*' instead of '*sedan*' and '*SUV*' ;

```
let arr = ['excavator','SUV','crossover','sedan','truck'] ;
arr = arr.map((ele,ind,ar) => {
  if (ele === 'crossover'){
    ar.splice(ind+1,1); 
    ar.splice(ind-1,1);
  }
  return ele + ": Sold."; 
});
return arr; //it produces ['excavator: Sold.','SUV: Sold.','crossover: Sold.',,]
```

Comment: Modifying an iterable while iterating has the stereotypical issue of messing up your iterator, which then has to be manually adjusted. If possible avoid such scenarios. In your case, the construction of the new array has already passed "SUV", so deleting that won't have the desired effect at that time, but will instead mess up the iterator.

Comment: If the end result of your array manipulation is an array of a *different length*, it's often an indicator that you might be better off foregoing the use of `.map()`. It sounds like you want a `.filter()` and a `.map()`, or you could combine the logic into a single `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first remove the elements and then map the array, here is an example:

```js
let arr = ['excavator','SUV','crossover','sedan','truck'];
arr.splice(arr.indexOf('crossover') - 1, 3, 'crossover');
arr = arr.map((ele) => {
  return ele + ": Sold."; 
});
console.log(arr);
```

The `.splice(..)` call replaces `SUV`, `crossover` and `sedan` with `crossover`

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove elements on a `.map` interation since the array size will change as well as the array indexes.

You should try something like this:

```js
let arr = ['excavator','SUV','crossover','sedan','truck'] ;
arr = arr.filter(element => element != "crossover");
arr = arr.map(ele => `${ele} :Sold.`);
console.log(arr);
```

Or, from an old school perspective:

```js
let arr = ['excavator','SUV','crossover','sedan','truck'];
let newArr=[]
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  if(arr[i] !== 'crossover')
     newArr.push(`${arr[i]} :Sold.`) 

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: This code is unuseful, he question about eliminate suv and sedan from the array, not crossover

Answer (score 0):

itus has the correct anwer, IMO but for the sake of fun this is an alternative way:

```
let arr = ['excavator','SUV','crossover','sedan','truck'] ;

let suvIndex = null;
const result = arr.map((item, index) => {
  if (item === "SUV") {
    suvIndex = index;
  }

  if(suvIndex && index <= suvIndex + 2) {
    return null;
  }

  return item;
}).filter(chunk => chunk)

console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vbz14fw6/